# onTime running on Workbook open not at specified time

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel 2013.

I wish to run a macro at two set times. So I have the code below. The issue I have is that it runs MyFunction when I open the workbook which I don't understand. I have specified it to run at 2.30pm & 3.30pm. Is there anyway of stopping it running the code at the wrong time?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:30:00"), MyFunction
Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:30:00"), MyFunction

End Sub

public Function MyFunction()

end function
```

Comment: Better to create 2 procedures and store the times in public variables and call the 2 procedures from workbook_open! See the reference here : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx

Comment: Procedure name should be a string, `"MyFunction"`.

Comment: And, FYI, you are not running Excel 2012 as that doesn't exist. ;)

Comment: I've put the procedure name as a string now and yes it doesn't run the function on opening the workbook so thanks. However when the time comes to run the function I get a message saying "Cannot run the macro, macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled". Macros aren't disabled and the function is there

Comment: Ah yes! Sorry that should be Excel 2013. I'll update

Comment: Its now working so thanks for your help. I had MyFunction in ThisWorkbook forgot to put it in a module

Comment: You only gave an [EarliestTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx) argument then made the workbook unavailable (as you claim they run when you open it)?